# How to iterate through auth_user table in django?

Tags: python, django

I have a model named cms_user which has an auth_user id as foreign key. So I want to iterate through cms_user model using request.user.

cms_user model:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from cms.models.masterCmsUserTypes import MasterCmsUserTypes


class CmsUser(models.Model):
    userId = models.ForeignKey(User,db_column='userId')
    userTypeId = models.ForeignKey(MasterCmsUserTypes,db_column='userTypeId')
    status = models.BooleanField(db_column="status", default=False, help_text="")
    isDelete = models.BooleanField(db_column="isDelete", default=False, help_text="")
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='createdAt', auto_now=True, help_text="")
    modifiedAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='modifiedAt', auto_now=True, help_text="")
    idv2 = models.IntegerField(db_column='idV2')
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'cms_user'
```

I want to iterate to cms_user using request.user

Comment: Why iterate. There should only be a OneToOneField here in the first place instead of a ForeignKey

Comment: I have created this table so I have mapped it with auth_user as a foreign key.So is there is a possibility that i can iterate through cms_user

Comment: But shouldn't it be only 1 user per cms user?

Comment: yes but I  have other table attached like one MasterCmsUserTypes in cms_user which is connected to it and i want to know how itteration can be done

Comment: Even if you have multiple tables attached to the model, there should only be one cms user per request.user right? Now you want to access the cms user from the request.user object. Am I correct? Iterration is done only when there are multiple elements involved e.g. When a single request.user can have multiple cms user per request.user

Comment: What is "I want to iterate through cms_user model using request.user." supposed to mean ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the `CmsUser` object related to the `request.user` object, there are 2 ways:

```
CmsUser.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

or

```
request.user.cmsuser_set.get()
```